# error with the modal pop up window closing up with onclick event javascript

Tags: javascript, css, function, popup, display

Trying to handle the popup window closing up. But I'm having an error. Is the issue reffered to the rhis keyword ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/tours-test-slick-v1uw96?file=/index.js:626-1309

```js
// Get the modal
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
const close = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtn");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
close.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == this.modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the close button by classname, this returns an array with all the elements so, you need to be especific with the button.

You can use `const close = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtn")[0];` or set an id to the button instead

Comment: You can also use `const close = modal.querySelector(".closeBtn")` to be more especific